# How to autostart pygtk program after boot

Tags: gtk, pygtk, autostart

I am working on python program in ubuntu that checks the internet connection and display a image on top panel using GTK and PYGTK module.
Now i am trying to autostart my python program after booting.Please help me

I tried autostart in /etc/rc.local but its showing this type of error**

GtkWarning: could not open display

> Warning: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE
>   (instance)' failed
>
> GtkWarning: IA__gdk_screen_get_root_window: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN
>   (screen)' failed
>
> GtkWarning: IA__gdk_screen_get_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN
>   (screen)' failed
>
> GtkWarning: IA__gdk_x11_display_get_xdisplay: assertion
>   'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed
>
> GtkWarning: IA__gdk_screen_get_number: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN
>   (screen)' failed

Answer (score 0):

That isn't designed for graphical applications, you should probably check out this spec: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/latest/

And for example throw a desktop file in `/etc/xdg/autostart`.

Comment: Could you give me some Desktop file example @TingPing